# windows 2008 DNS Website without www?

Tags: windows, iis-7, dns

I have a site on my server that only works with a www.
example: 
http://www.dartmouthplayers.ns.ca/
works but without it, it does not.
http://dartmouthplayers.ns.ca/

But the site's bindings has both listed:

[image]

and the DNS has the blank host record:
[image]

What did I not set right?

It's odd because:
http://dartmouthplayers.ns.ca/ - returns a 500 error
and http://randomtexthere.dartmouthplayers.ns.ca/ - returns a server not found error

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would ask this on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com).  From my end, http://dartmouthplayers.ns.ca/ works fine  and http://www.dartmouthplayers.ns.ca/ is returning a 500.  DNS looks fine as both resolve to 74.84.132.101.  It looks like an IIS configuration problem.